# Leaflet: panTo Web Mercator coordinates (EPSG 3857)

Tags: javascript, maps, gis, leaflet

I have a standard leaflet map showing a tile layer. Now leaflet only lets you use `panTo` method using LatLng for example,

```
map.panTo(new L.LatLng(40.17, -98.12));
```

How will I use above panTo method if my coordinates are in `EPSG:3857` for example `(3679364.68,-9096106.74)` ?

This is quite simple to to in Openlayers as once you define a map projection everything works in that projection. But Leaflet always works on latlng on the outside.

Any simple way to accomplish this using **leaflet library**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can get it working if I use [proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) library to transform the coordinates by doing this:

```
var source = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:3857');
var dest = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4326');
var p = new Proj4js.Point(-9096106.74,3679364.68); //this takes x,y
Proj4js.transform(source, dest, p);
this.map.setView(new L.LatLng(p.y, p.x),zoom);
```

But this is still not an ideal solution as it taxes me a Megabyte for for including the library. I am still looking for a leaflet solution. Knowing that internally leaflet already uses EPSG:3857 to fetch tiles, this shouldn't  be this difficult.

```
Update
```

To do this purely in Leaflet, look at @ARsl's answer. Only reason I still accept this as my answer because,  still feel uncomfortable doing the projection calculations like that (not that they are wrong), and just for that reason I don't accept this answer.  Plus proj4js as added advantages of supporting many more datums.

```
UPDATE
```

Check @Moos'SamuelSilver 's comment for this answer for another way to do this in  leaflet without proj4js:

> Leaflet.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(Leaflet.point(x,y)) does the job pretty
> well. Source and further informations:
> leafletjs.com/reference.html#crs

Comment: Isn't the proj4js lib only like 70kb?  I do agree though, wish this functionality was in leaflet as well.

Comment: @RyanM Thats correct and usually I would gladly use it. But in this particular application I am fighting to save on bytes very literally. So it hurts having to import another lib for such a trivial task that Leaflet already knows how to do on the inside.

Comment: Leaflet.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(Leaflet.point(x,y)) does the job pretty well.
Source and further informations: https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#crs

But i expect this is a newer feature then this Q&A is old.

Comment: @Moos'SamuelSilver yes indeed it's easier to do now and like you said the question was before that was added to Leaflet. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Leaflet lets you use panTo method by unproject 3857 point. If you don't want to use proj4js library it also achieve in leaflet.

```
var point = new L.Point(3679364.68,-9096106.74); // Lon/Lat
var earthRadius = 6378137;
var latlng = L.Projection.SphericalMercator.unproject(point.divideBy(earthRadius));

map.panTo(new L.LatLng(latlng.lat, latlng.lng));
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! great answer! I still feel uncomfortable doing the projection calculations like that (not that they are wrong), and just for that reason I don't accept this answer.  Plus proj4js as added advantages of supporting many more datums.

Answer (score 2):

I also haven't found any built-in method to convert EPSG:3857 coordinates to LatLng.

LeafLet crs class `L.CRS.EPSG3857` has only `project` method which converts `L.LatLng` to `L.Point` in EPSG:3857 coordinates.
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/geo/crs/CRS.EPSG3857.js

But it is quite easy to extend it with `unproject` method:

```
L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject = function (point) { // Point -> LatLng
  var earthRadius = 6378137;
      projectionPoint = L.point(point).divideBy(earthRadius);

  return this.projection.unproject(projectionPoint);
};
```

Then you can use it with `panTo` method:

```
map.panTo(map.options.crs.unproject([1372720.6476878107, 5690559.995203462]));
```

or:

```
map.panTo(L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject([1372720.6476878107, 5690559.995203462]));
```